# IE adds two underscores to cookie at document.cookie.replace

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

This is the code. "data" comes from PHP and it's the image source of an image:

```
document.cookie = "imagePath=" + data;
var myCookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)imagePath\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

It works very well in Chrome and FF - console.log returns **nameoffile.jpg**, but for some reason Internet Explorer returns: **nameoffile.jpg __**

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Fount this link while browsing, hope this would help you.
http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/internet-explorer-eats-cookies-with-underscores-in-the-hostname/